# Strip everything but letters and numbers and replace spaces that are in the sentence with hyphens

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm trying to parse a string similar to the way StackOverflow's tags work. So letters and numbers are allowed, but everything else should be stripped. Also spaces should be replaced with hyphens, but only if they are inside the word and not have disallowed characters before them.

This is what I have right now:

```
label = label.trim();
label = label.toLowerCase();
label = label.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/g,'');
label = label.replace(/ /g, '-');
```

This works but with a few caveats, for example this:

```
 / this. is-a %&&66 test tag    .   <-- (4 spaces here, the arrow and this text is not part of the test string)
```

Becomes:

```
-this-is-a66-test-tag----
```

Expected:

```
this-is-a66-test-tag
```

I looked at this to get what I have now:

[How to remove everything but letters, numbers, space, exclamation and question mark from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343451/how-to-remove-everything-but-letters-numbers-space-exclamation-and-question-m)

But like I said it doesn't fully give me what I'm looking for.

How do I tweak my code to give me what I want?

Comment: Just `trim()` the `label` before the last `replace`. `label = label.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-');`

Comment: Or change your last line to `label = label.replace(/\s+/g, '-');`

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yes, `\s+` is the right one (edited my top comment), but `trim()` is still required to avoid the leading/trailing `-`s

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew agree, without that there will be a trailing `-`

Comment: Well, after testing it out, it seems the expected result is not clear. I get `this-isa-66-test-tag`, while `this-is-a66-test-tag` is expected. Why? Note that existing `-`  are removed with the first `replace`. If you add `-` at the end of the first regex, you may get `this-is-a-66-test-tag`. Is it better?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There was a typo on my part. Apologies. Regardless of what you enter the format should always be `xxx-xxx` for example. Not `-xxx-xxx-    ` or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make 2 changes:

- Since you do not replace all whitespace with the first `replace` you need to replace all whitespace chars with the second regex (so, a plain space must be replaced with `\s`, and even better, with `\s+` to replace multiple consecutive occurrences),
- To get rid of leading/trailing hyphens in the end, use `trim()` after the first replace.

So, the actual fix will look like

```js
var label = " / this. is-a %&&66 test tag    .   ";
label = label.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s-]/ig,'')
  .trim()
  .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
  .toLowerCase();
console.log(label); // => this-isa-66-test-tag
```

Note that if you add `-` to the first regex, `/[^a-z0-9\s-]/ig`, you will also keep the original hyphens in the output and it will look like `this-is-a-66-test-tag` for the current test case.

Comment: Appears to cover all cases as far as I can see, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `trim` just before changing all spaces with hyphens.

You can use this function:

```js
function tagit(label) {
label = label.toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/g,'');
return label.trim().replace(/ /g, '-'); }

var str = 'this. is-a %&&66 test tag    .'

console.log(tagit(str));
//=> "this-isa-66-test-tag"
```