# Javascript - Using .replace to remove the word "and" from string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string that I am attempting to remove the word "and" from. I am attempting this by using the .replace method in javascript. I am able to remove the word "and" but the end result is not what I am expecting.

I would like my string to be returned similar to the `console.log(testString)` where the entire string is returned as `"i-have-a-test-test-test"` without any spacing in between. Currently, my attempt with `console.log(newString)` returns the string without the `-` in between each word.

My expected outcome is to have a return result as :

`I-have-a-test-test-test`

```js
const string = "I have a test and test and test" 

const newString = string.replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9]*|\s*)\s\and/g, '-')

const testString = string.replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9]*|\s*)\s/g, '-')
console.log(newString)
console.log(testString)
```

Comment: Is something like `string.replace(/\band\b/g, "").split(/ +/).join("-")` what you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string)

Comment: Also relevant: [Strip everything but letters and numbers and replace spaces that are in the sentence with hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47457447) - it can work the same but instead of the alphanumeric regex, you can replace `and` followed by replacing all spaces to dashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var s = "I have a test and test and test" 
s = s.replace(/ and /g, '-').replace(/ /g, '-')
```

or

```
var s = "I have a test and test and test" 
s = s.replace(/ and | /g, '-')
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const string = "I have a test and test and test"; 
const string2= string.split(" ").join("-").split("and").join("").split("--").join("-");
console.log(string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give your expected outcome based on the scenario you provided:

```
const string = "I have a test and test and test" 
const newString = string.replaceAll('and ', '').replaceAll(' ','-')
console.log(newString)
```

String.prototype.replaceAll() source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll